# Returning Json with nodeJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js

I try to learn nodeJS and AngularJS using Clash of clan API available here `https://developer.clashofclans.com/#/`

My JSON api's return is truncated and i don't know how get the full response.

there is my app.js wrinting with node and express :

```
var   express       = require('express')
, https         = require('https')
, bodyParser    = require('body-parser')
, request       = require('request')
, app           = express()
, http_port     = 3000;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser());

var options = {
    host: 'api.clashofclans.com',
    port: 443,
    path: '/v1/clans/' + encodeURIComponent("#PP8JC9RQ"),
    headers : {
    accept : "application/json",
    authorization : "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsImtpZCI6IjI4YTMxOGY3LTAwMDAtYTFlYi03ZmExLTJjNzQzM2M2Y2NhNSJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJzdXBlcmNlbGwiLCJhdWQiOiJzdXBlcmNlbGw6Z2FtZWFwaSIsImp0aSI6ImQ4Njg1OGFhLWQzZTUtNDNiOC05MTM1LTBjNzI1ZjI4OGFiMiIsImlhdCI6MTQ1NjMwMTE5MSwic3ViIjoiZGV2ZWxvcGVyLzk1YWM0YjdmLTY5NTQtMDE3MC01ZjAyLTcxNjY1ZDMzYjUwNyIsInNjb3BlcyI6WyJjbGFzaCJdLCJsaW1pdHMiOlt7InRpZXIiOiJkZXZlbG9wZXIvc2lsdmVyIiwidHlwZSI6InRocm90dGxpbmcifSx7ImNpZHJzIjpbIjg3LjIzMS4yMTMuMTU0Il0sInR5cGUiOiJjbGllbnQifV19.SYqeSAF-0_bM1eS2-hnovvj5j-I0SQpdr_kySIiBKw9OkrNuBzZAOAOkiH3fzdKSkcHaJfXzWdXr8JozFfAmJA"
},
method: 'GET'
};

//  Route par défaut
    app.get("/members", function(req, res) {
    console.log("-------------------------------------\n\nroot path !! Let's get clan infos from coc api\n\n-------------------------------------");
    var req = https.request(options, function(response){

        response.on('data', function (chunk) {          
            console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
            //    in console JSON is full but in my html JSON is truncated..
            res.send(chunk);
        });         
    });

    req.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
    });

    req.end();

    });


app.listen(http_port,function(){
    console.log("Listening on " + http_port);
});
```

If someone can teach to a nook :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is sending the first chunk of the response immediately back to the user. You need to wait until the entire HTTP response is done. Try something like this:

```
app.get("/members", function(req, res) {
    var req = https.request(options, function(response){
    var httpResult = '';
    response.on('data', function (chunk) {          
        console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
        httpResult += chunk;
    });         
    response.on('end', function() {
       res.send(httpResult);
    });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

req.end();

});
```

See how I append to a var each time the data event is called and when it is done - *then* I send the output.

Comment: it seemed to me I tried this solution with no success.. works as expected thx a lot !!

Answer (score 1):

Because you use `send` method instead `write` (send non-streaming). Try this:

```
app.get("/members", function(req, res) {

    https.request(options, function(response){

        response.on('data', function (chunk) {          
            res.write(chunk);
        });         

        response.on('end', function () {          
            res.end();
        });         

    }).end();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

`response` is a stream, you can simply pipe it to `res`:

```
app.get("/members", function(req, res) {
  https.request(options, function(response) {
    response.pipe(res);
  });
});
```

Comment: do i need to put `response.pipe(res)` inside `response.on('data', function (chunk) {});` ??

Comment: @akio No, that one line is enough. `pipe` handles 'data' events for you and do all the `read()` and `write()` needed when it's needed. The data flows nicely between *response* and *res* like water flows in [pipes](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=pipe&tbs=imgo:1#tbs=imgo:1&tbm=isch&q=pipe+water).